# Convenient way for executing lazy futures which are contained in the main future

Tags: scala

There is the following situation:

```
type LazyFuture = () => Future

val mainFuture: Future[Seq[LazyFuture]] = Future {
    ...
    // some actions which can throw exceptions
    ...

    // inner lazy futures as result of main future
    // they has to be executed only if the main future is completed successfully
    val xs: Seq[LazyFuture] = Seq(
      () => Future(1),
      () => Future(2),
      ...
      () => Future(N)
    )
    xs
}
```

Is there convenient way for executing inner lazy futures in case when the `mainFuture` is executed successfully. The following pseudo illustrates the task:

```
val resultFuture:Future[Any] = 
      if(mainFuture is success) 
        // exec inner lazy futures
        Future.sequence(mainFuture.result.map(c => c())) 
      else
        // nothing
        Future.successful(Unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution for the above task.

```
type LazyFuture = () => Future

val mainFuture: Future[Seq[LazyFuture]] = Future {

    val xs: Seq[LazyFuture] = Seq(
      () => Future(1),
      () => Future(2),
      ...
      () => Future(N)
    )
    xs
}

val promise = Promise[Future[Seq[Any]]]()

mainFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(xs: Seq[LazyFuture]) =>
    val eventualSeq: Future[Seq[Any]] = Future.sequence(xs.map(c => c()))
    promise success eventualSeq
  case Failure(t) => promise failure t
}

val resultFuture: Future[Any] = promise.future.flatten
```

Is this solution good enough and may any problems appear?